# Android SeekBar customization

Tags: android

I have to create SeekBar style for Android and can't figure out how to do this. Here is picture of the final result (which I'd like to reach).

[image]

Let's start with SeekBar's background. I've tried to split it into three parts: left rounded end, repeatable piece of the middle part, and right rounded end. And them should be joined with next code (foo_background.xml).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:clipOrientation="horizontal" >

    <bitmap
        android:antialias="true"
        android:dither="false"
        android:filter="false"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/foo_left"
        android:tileMode="disabled" />
    <bitmap
        android:antialias="true"
        android:dither="false"
        android:filter="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/foo_middle"
        android:tileMode="repeat" />
    <bitmap
        android:antialias="true"
        android:dither="false"
        android:filter="false"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/foo_right"
        android:tileMode="disabled" />

</clip>
```

Which is used in SeekBar's background drawable file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/foo_background" />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/seek_bar_progress" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

But as a result of all this stuff I see an empty (or better say I don't see it) SeekBar progress line.

Does any know how to do this in right way?
Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: you can watch tutorial in link http://webtutsdepot.com/2011/12/03/android-sdk-tutorial-seekbar-example/

Answer (score 2):

Try below links here you will have some information about the customization of seekbars.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/androids-seekbar-your-way/943

OR

http://developer-dot-android.blogspot.in/2012/03/custom-seekbar-tutorial.html

This may help you....

Comment: Thanks, but I saw almost all this links before. Them didn't help me :(